# A strange Problem about gdi+ bitmap!

Tags: gdi+, bitmap

I am using the following code to get a Bitmap point,

(width = 800, height = 600);

```
Bitmap* m_BitmapCanvasCore = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
```

but the m_BitmapCanvasCore always is NULL...
Is there any thing wrong about gdi+? Or any namespace polution I need to avoid?
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call [GdiplusStartup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077(VS.85).aspx) before creating the Bitmap?